# why when editing jstree node - it's color return to default?

Tags: jquery, jstree

I created jstree node with red color:

```
sel = ref.create_node(sel, {});

if(sel) {
     $('#'+sel).css("color", "red");
}
```

The node created well, but when I edit it with `edit(sel)`, it's color returns to the black default.

How can I edit it without change the color? Thanks!

Comment: what is sel returns it is a id

Comment: I dont understand you. what do you mean? as I wrote - all work well, just the problem I mentioned.